# TMUX - Pane Resizing not working when detached?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, tmux

I've been learning TMUX recently.
The main motivation for learning it, is to be able to write shell scripts for layouts. This obviously includes splitting windows into multiple sub-panes with specific heights and widths.

**The Problem:**

When in an attached tmux session, I can execute this command: `Ctrl+b+: -> resize-pane -y 8`

This resizes the currently selected *(vertical)* pane to an absolute amount of 8 lines.

***However.*** When I write a script to perform this action, before the session is attached, it either doesn't work or consider the given number relative instead of absoloute:

```
tmux new -s test -d
tmux send-keys -t test 'ls /' C-m
tmux split-window -v -t test
tmux resize-pane -t test -y 8       #<--- Not working correctly
tmux send-keys -t test 'ls ~' C-m
tmux attach -t test
```

Is `resize-pane -t` accepting not the session name, or something?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: At a guess, there's no selected pane because it's not an active session. Does `-t test:0.0` work?

Comment: There is always an active pane and current window, attached or not.

Comment: Related to https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/1774 ?

Answer (score 7):

The resize probably is working but the unattached session you have created is much smaller that the terminal you then attach to so when you attach tmux will resize the pane.

Try adding `-x- -y-` to `new-session`:

```
tmux new -s test -d -x- -y-
```

Comment: This seemed promising, but no It did not change anything.

Comment: If your tmux is too old for -x- then you may need to do eg -x$COLUMNS -y$LINES or give an explicit size. Try doing the commands manually and check the size with `tmux lsw` after the `new`.

Comment: Worked for me (v2.9a, v3.0a). Saved the day! Thanks @NicholasMarriott.

Comment: That did it, what does '-x-' and '-y-' mean? why isn't it documented anywhere?